# add one column below another one in r

Tags: r

I have an issue in adding one column below another column.

I have a data like this :

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 1 |
| 99 | 42 | 0 |

And I want that column 2 be below 1:

| Heading 1 | value |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 |
| 99 | 0 |
| 34 | 1 |
| 42 | 0 |

Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```r
data.frame(Heading = c(df$`Heading 1`, df$`Heading 2`), value = rep(df$Value, 2))
#>   Heading value
#> 1      12     1
#> 2      99     0
#> 3      34     1
#> 4      42     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also `rbind` the two dataframes together:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
list(
heading1=c(12, 99),
heading2=c(34, 42),
value=c(1,0)))

rbind(df %>% select(heading1, value),
      df %>% select(heading2, value) %>% rename(heading1 = heading2))


  heading1 value
1       12     1
2       99     0
3       34     1
4       42     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Completely `tidyverse` way, to my mind:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
list(
heading1=c(12, 99),
heading2=c(34, 42),
value=c(1,0)))

output <- bind_rows(
  df %>% select(heading1, value), 
  df %>% select(heading1 = heading2, value)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unlist` and `cbind` the result.

```
cbind("Heading 1" = unlist(df[1:2]), df[3])
#          Heading 1 value
#heading11        12     1
#heading12        99     0
#heading21        34     1
#heading22        42     0
```

Or without the names.

```
cbind("Heading 1" = unlist(df[1:2], use.names = FALSE), df[3])
#  Heading 1 value
#1        12     1
#2        99     0
#3        34     1
#4        42     0
```